# Unable to take cluster backups using medusa

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a simple 3 node cluster with some sample data. I want to take backup (To S3) of the cluster and restore it in different cluster.
I can take node backup and restore however cluster level backup never seems to be working. It is throwing the following error.

Cassandra version - **3.10**, OS - Amazon linux 2 - centos

```
[2022-05-20 06:37:20,534] INFO: Creating snapshots on all nodes
[2022-05-20 06:37:20,534] INFO: Executing "nodetool -Dcom.sun.jndi.rmiURLParsing=legacy snapshot -t medusa-samp" on following nodes ['nodecassandra-2.localdomain', 'nodecassandra-3.localdomain', 'nodecassandra-1.localdomain'] with a parallelism/pool size of 500
[2022-05-20 06:37:21,129] ERROR: Job executing "nodetool -Dcom.sun.jndi.rmiURLParsing=legacy snapshot -t medusa-samp" ran and finished with errors on following nodes: ['nodecassandra-1.localdomain', 'nodecassandra-2.localdomain', 'nodecassandra-3.localdomain']
[2022-05-20 06:37:21,130] INFO: [nodecassandra-2.localdomain] [err] /bin/bash: nodetool: command not found
[2022-05-20 06:37:21,130] INFO: nodecassandra-2.localdomain-stderr: /bin/bash: nodetool: command not found
[2022-05-20 06:37:21,130] INFO: [nodecassandra-3.localdomain] [err] /bin/bash: nodetool: command not found
[2022-05-20 06:37:21,130] INFO: nodecassandra-3.localdomain-stderr: /bin/bash: nodetool: command not found
[2022-05-20 06:37:21,130] INFO: [nodecassandra-1.localdomain] [err] /bin/bash: nodetool: command not found
[2022-05-20 06:37:21,130] INFO: nodecassandra-1.localdomain-stderr: /bin/bash: nodetool: command not found
[2022-05-20 06:37:21,130] ERROR: Some nodes failed to create the snapshot.
[2022-05-20 06:37:21,130] ERROR: This error happened during the cluster backup: Some nodes failed to create the snapshot.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/medusa/backup_cluster.py", line 64, in orchestrate
backup.execute(cql_session_provider)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/medusa/backup_cluster.py", line 146, in execute
self._create_snapshots()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/medusa/backup_cluster.py", line 163, in _create_snapshots
raise Exception(err_msg)
Exception: Some nodes failed to create the snapshot.
[2022-05-20 06:37:21,131] ERROR: Something went wrong! Attempting to clean snapshots and exit.
[2022-05-20 06:37:21,131] INFO: Executing "nodetool -Dcom.sun.jndi.rmiURLParsing=legacy clearsnapshot -t medusa-samp" on following nodes ['nodecassandra-2.localdomain', 'nodecassandra-3.localdomain', 'nodecassandra-1.localdomain'] with a parallelism/pool size of 1
[2022-05-20 06:37:22,290] ERROR: Job executing "nodetool -Dcom.sun.jndi.rmiURLParsing=legacy clearsnapshot -t medusa-samp" ran and finished with errors on following nodes: ['nodecassandra-1.localdomain', 'nodecassandra-2.localdomain', 'nodecassandra-3.localdomain']
[2022-05-20 06:37:22,290] INFO: [nodecassandra-2.localdomain] [err] /bin/bash: nodetool: command not found
[2022-05-20 06:37:22,290] INFO: nodecassandra-2.localdomain-stderr: /bin/bash: nodetool: command not found
[2022-05-20 06:37:22,290] INFO: [nodecassandra-3.localdomain] [err] /bin/bash: nodetool: command not found
[2022-05-20 06:37:22,290] INFO: nodecassandra-3.localdomain-stderr: /bin/bash: nodetool: command not found
[2022-05-20 06:37:22,290] INFO: [nodecassandra-1.localdomain] [err] /bin/bash: nodetool: command not found
[2022-05-20 06:37:22,290] INFO: nodecassandra-1.localdomain-stderr: /bin/bash: nodetool: command not found
[2022-05-20 06:37:22,291] ERROR: Some nodes failed to clear the snapshot. Cleaning snapshots manually is recommended
```

1. I have added path variables for cassandra bin, nodetool.
2. Added CASSANDRA_HOME, CASSANDRA_CONF in /etc/profile.d/cassandra.sh.
3. Added ssh details in medusa.ini. Provided cassandra_conf file path,
   storage (s3) details and ssh details in medusa.ini.

Am i missing anything else ?

Comment: the bash errors indicate that nodetool can't be found. Is it not installed, or not in the path?

Comment: Yes this was an issue with sudo execution, I was able to take cluster backups after adding nodetool, medussa-wrapper paths for secure_path variable in /etc/sudoers file.